# Application icon not showing oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

I installed oracle database 19c and apex version 22.2 ,

and I make menu page but some icons not showing

what is the reason ?

see the application image and table data :

[image]

open the image please and see HIS home page , OPD system and emergency department the icon not appear next to the name but the other icons appeared for MRN registration and inpatient system

I got the icons names from the following site :

```
https://fontawesome.com/search
```

Comment: *Which* icons are "some icons"? Obviously, we can't see something that isn't visible, so you'll have to tell us. Also, how did you "make menu page"? You should provide as much info as possible if you expect someone to assist.

Comment: @Littlefoot open the image please and see HIS home page , OPD system and emergency department the icon not appear next to the name but the other icons appeared for MRN registration and inpatient system

Comment: Aha, that's on the left hand side. OK, which values did you put into appropriate properties? Which Apex version do you use? Note that not all *fontawesome* icons are available on all Apex versions.